# Error MSB8020 : The build tools for WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0') cannot be found

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to shift my project build from VS2019 to VS2022. But while building the project it is giving me this error.

*The build tools for WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0') cannot be found. To build using the WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 build tools, please install WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".*

It was building fine with the previous version. I have made the following changes

- MSVC v142 – VS 2019  --------> MSVC v143 – VS 2022?
- Windows 10 SDK --------> Windows 11 SDK
- C++ MFC for latest v142 build tools -------> C++ MFC for latest v143 build tools
- C++ Modules for latest v142 -------> C++ Modules for lates v143
- C++ 2019 Redistributable MSMs -------> C++ 2022 Redistributable MSMs
- .NET Framework 4.6 targeting pack ------> .NET Framework 4.8 targeting pack
  (4.6 targeting pack also needed as it is dependency for Visual Studio
  SDK)

Comment: Hi, what is the version of your [WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/system-requirements#supported-operating-systems) When building in VS2022? You can try to modify WindowsKernelModeDriver's version in PlatformToolset of your project file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install WDK too
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk
as part of it is installation of VS2022 integration so install it too or it will not work